# How I get input value when button is click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have same html code but id is different for button
now I want to get value of input field that is nearest to button which is click.

Here is my html code:

```
<input id="btn-input" class="form-control input-sm chat_input message" type="text" placeholder="Write your message here..." ng-model="messageToSend">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="btn_chat" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_chat" value="38">Send</button>
    </span>

<input id="btn-input" class="form-control input-sm chat_input message" type="text" placeholder="Write your message here..." ng-model="messageToSend">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="btn_chat" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_chat" value="39">Send</button>
    </span>
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_chat', function (e) {
    alert("Button id: "+$(this).val());
    alert($(this).closest('input .message').val());
});
```

It will gives button value but input value is undefined

Comment: `.btn_chat` refers class attributes. You have `id="btn_chat"` an ID, which is duplicated. Please change it.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend duplicate `Id's` the value will always display in the first `message` input.

Comment: remove the `id` attribute and change to this: `.parent().prev('input.message')`

Comment: i removed id attributes still it's showing undefined

Comment: @jai thanks `$(this).parent().prev('input.message').val()` this is working

Comment: @RahulPatil it's just a quick fix. use `.closest()` method for concrete solution because of anything your markup structure changes `.parent()` will fail. Try doing as rory's answer. That is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should remove the duplicate `id` attributes and use classes to group your elements instead.

You can then use `closest()` to traverse the DOM to the nearest parent `span` and then use `prev()` to get the `input`. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_chat', function (e) {
    var $input = $(this).closest('span').prev('input.message');
    alert($input.val());
});
```

Note the removal of the space between `input` and `.message` in the selector as we are looking for both of those properties on a single element.

Answer (score 0):

there should be difference between `ID` and `CLASS` and
you are referring the class `.btn-chat` which is in both elements.
Remember the `ID` should be unique so that it will be identified by your handler.

Answer (score 0):

you have repeated your ID's

but a simple jquery can return you answer:

```
$(".btn_chat").click(function(){
    alert($(this).parents('.input-group').find('input').val());
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/happy2deepak/3nbpfxg5/1/)